# Classification threshold based on (discrete) data

Tags: math, statistics

I want to know how I can calculate the classification threshold of two classes A and B based on discrete data samples. It can be assumed that the two classes are uniformly distributed but appear mixed around the unknown threshold.

x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,11,12,13,14,16,17,19,20,21,22]
y = ["A","A","A","A","A","A","B","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B"]

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0ecV.png)